# Absolute vs Fixed Positioning

Tags: html, css

I have a custom dialog box which is shown when I click a button. After the dialog box is shown I show a overlay. The height and width of the overlay is `100% x 100%`. Here comes the problem, the height 100% just gets the height of the browser window so when I scroll down on the page it remains at the top. How can I set its height to full page height not browser's?

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ryJEW/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div class="description" style="text-align: justify;">Some text..(whole big text is in the fiddle didn't wrote here to shorten the code :))</div>
<div style="text-align: right">
    <button id="offer_help">Offer Help</button>
</div>
<div class="offer_a_help">
    <textarea rows="5">Write a short experience about yourself</textarea>
    <textarea rows="5">Write what do you want in return</textarea>
    <button id="send_offer">Send Offer</button>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#overlay {
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#offer_help {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px #aaa;
}
.offer_a_help {
    display: none;
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    top: calc(100%/2 - 350px/2);
    left: calc(100%/2 - 250px/2);
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    text-align: center;
}
.offer_a_help textarea {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 2px;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
.offer_a_help textarea:first-child {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.offer_a_help button {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

**How can I set its height to full page height not browser's?**

Comment: Now you're going to edit the entire question? What's the point?

Comment: rep fishing. it is a brand new sport.

Comment: in which way this is related to javascript/jquery ???

Comment: :'( Guys I am sorry, please delete this question if anyone here is a moderator! I didn't knew that it was going to be this bad! Actually I myself started to solve this after posting this and then realized to post this as the answer

Comment: I didn't knew that :'(

Comment: please is there anyway I can delete this question? it ruining my whole SO profile

Comment: a few downvotes will not ruin anything. Keep contributing and this blemish will no longer be noticed.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui You can use the search feature to find if there are similar questions, in fact before you create a question, SO will list out possible similar questions. Please spend some effort in trying to solve the problem yourself and do your own research before posting a question that you could easily solve in 3 minutes after asking.

Comment: OK! :D @projeqht thanks for that super duper hint! I will take care next time! thank all you guys for this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`position: absolute` takes the element out of line with the document. so the height is that of the viewport, and the top,left values are static. Change this to `position: fixed` and you will see better results.

Answer (score 1):

Use position:fixed.

http://jsfiddle.net/ryJEW/2/

```
#overlay {
opacity: 0.5;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: black;
display: none;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```